# Does 'php://input' include the client's device ID information?

Tags: php, android, webserver

When I print `$data = file_get_contents('php://input')`,It printed lots of messy code. I want to know from the php server which android device has uploaded a certain file to the server. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you looking for device model, or the unique/personally-identifying device id?

Comment: the unique/personally-identifying device id I think, the client are some android mobile phone.

Comment: If the request is a standard HTTP request, then php://input will be very well-formed, and quite readable (at least the first dozen lines or so. If you say it's "messy", then the client may be using a proprietary format for the request; but this seems unlikely. If you wrap that print call in <pre> tags, is it still "messy", or does it start to look clean?

Comment: It is the same as before when I used the <pre>.I should clarify that the content of the file is readable.but  before and after the file body,there is some character like: PK then some square

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question to include the readable parts.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't messy code, it's details about the request which you do not understand.

Go learn how the HTTP protocol works, you can't tackle this problem if you don't understand what you're working with.

You can only find out what a user-agent provides. If they are not sending a request header over HTTP with a device version number, then no you will not get that.

Typically the OS is included in the User-agent string. This is likely to be the only place you'll find anything close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Should I install a tool that I check the http message to analysis it. Do you have some for recommendation?thanks.

Comment: the client is not writen by me.I find this in the client code. HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();params.setParameter("http.useragent", "NCW Client:"+ CollectorConstants.DATA_VERSION). Does the client device information exsit in "NCW Client:"+ CollectorConstants.DATA_VERSION, if there is any?

Comment: You can use PHP's $_SERVER superglobal to inspect what the client sends: `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`. That will echo whatever `"NCW Client:"+ CollectorConstants.DATA_VERSION` is on the device (if that's the code that actually builds the request).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the specific user, the best you can do (by design of many of the systems between you and the device), is implement "sessions" using [HTTP cookies](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt). If the requests are coming from a browser, once you set a cookie, every subsequent request from that individual user will have the same cookie with it.

The general pattern we use is to look for an existing cookie, and if there isn't one (i.e. new user): create a unique random string, store it somewhere on the server associated with this "user", and then send it to the user as a cookie.

[The PHP session features](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) can greatly assist you in this.

***Keep in mind*** you can only track a user in this anonymous way. You cannot get an actual device ID from the device unless you also wrote the app on the device which is sending the request. ***and this is good***.

Comment: I think the device send the request about its device.But I don't know how to receive it.Is it in 'php://input'?Can I change the format of 'php://input',so I can read what is in it.